# Is Bruce Banner's human body less fragile because he is also the Hulk?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-ragnarok, the-incredible-hulk-2008

In *Thor: Ragnarok*, when Bruce Banner falls from the space ship onto the rainbow walkway to help in the fight against Hela, he falls expecting to change into the Hulk - only to hit the ground as Banner, yet doesn't sustain any injuries.

Is this movie magic or does his Bruce Banner form share some of the healing/near indestructible qualities of the Hulk? I don't know the comics that well so apologies if this is covered there so answered for MCU but would like to hear other non-MCU points in the comments.

Comment: Banner soars through the air. It's an awe-inspiring image as we follow Banner's trajectory downwards. His face is determined, arms churning, ready to Hulk out...

...except it doesn't happen. Worry washes over his face.

SPLAT! Banner FACEPLANTS on the bridge, seeming to break every bone in his body. He looks dead.

Pause. Fenris SNIFFS him curiously. We notice one vein on Banner's neck PUMPING GREEN. Then- Banner suddenly EXPLODES UP as THE INCREDIBLE HULK, UPPER-CUTTING Fenris in the jaw! - https://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Thor-Ragnarok.html

Comment: @Valorum so just before impact he begins to change and minute change is enough to save him from a proper SPLAT!?

Comment: Historically, he's effectively immortal in either form. Any damage that occurs to him is repaired as soon as he hulks

Comment: I feel like the MCU banner is no more durable than any other man, but that his immediate transformation into Hulk when seriously injured makes Banner practically impervious to serious damage. It's like if I was completely broke, but had a rich friend who provided for all my needs and gave me a limitless allowance to buy anything I might want. I wouldn't be wealthy myself, but there wouldn't be much practical difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Banner is just as fragile as a normal human being. We have seen him get hurt in his human form.

- While the first Hulk film is not considered canon, we do see Banner being subdued by the military.
- In *The Incredible Hulk*, we see him cutting his finger in the soda factory, which causes drops of blood fall into the bottles below.
- In *Thor: Ragnarok*, we do see him fall flat onto the bridge, and there's all the chance in the world that he broke a huge number of bones. However, he then Hulks out, and Hulk mode essentially insta-heals all his wounds and breaks.

So in summary, No. Bruce Banner doesn't share the physical characteristics of the Hulk.

In the comics, he dies a rather mundane death when Hawkeye shoots him with a special arrow that he helped design, meaning an arrow can penetrate him just like a normal human.

Answer (score 11):

It doesn't seem like it's harder to break his bones or do soft tissue damage to him.  But things that should kill him just don't.  Instead he transforms, instantly healing the damage.  His comic book counterpart healed back from an apparent death that Banner had planned to instantly kill himself.  His movie self described how he put a bullet into his brain in as close to instant death as is reasonably possible and he simply transformed and spat the bullet out.  Ultimately Bruce Banner is a man with superpowers and not a separate being from the Hulk and their apparent distinct personalities are the product of his own psychological issues.  So even with MCU Banner it's dubious whether any damage that left him with most of his flesh could actually kill him.  Damage just doesn't stick to the Hulk, and ultimately Banner is the Hulk.

Comment: The "spit out a bullet" story might actually support the fact that Bruce's regular body *is* more durable, just because the bullet was still there to be spit out & there was no exit wound.

Comment: @david Johnston I like your point and it explains why Banner can't be killed  but I don't think it answers my question. Valorum quote answers why Banner didn't get hurt in the fall but say BB is unconcious or is sedated or just cant transform, would receive an injury the same as a normal human?

Comment: He probably was unconscious after shooting a bullet into his brain.  His comic book counter was definitely unconscious after Hawkeye shot him in the brain with a gimmick arrow.  If that had any effect it was just "it took longer for him to revive as the Hulk".

Comment: Xen2050 a low calibre bullet is very likely to remain inside the skull.  When it does that is actually more deadly because it bounces inside.